# Odoo14 service keep crash (Dumping stacktrace of limit exceeding threads before reloading)

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

i face the following error

```
2022-05-30 15:00:26,943 1940 WARNING ? odoo.service.server: Server memory limit (4934283264) reached.
2022-05-30 15:00:26,954 1940 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Dumping stacktrace of limit exceeding threads before reloading
2022-05-30 15:00:26,997 1940 INFO ? odoo.tools.misc:
# Thread: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140592199739200)> (db:n/a) (uid:n/a) (url:n/a)
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo-bin", line 8, in <module>
  odoo.cli.main()
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo/cli/command.py", line 61, in main
  o.run(args)
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo/cli/server.py", line 178, in run
  main(args)
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo/cli/server.py", line 172, in main
  rc = odoo.service.server.start(preload=preload, stop=stop)
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo/service/server.py", line 1298, in start
  rc = server.run(preload, stop)
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo/service/server.py", line 546, in run
  dumpstacks(thread_idents=[thread.ident for thread in self.limits_reached_threads])
File: "/opt/odoo/odoo14/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 957, in dumpstacks
  for line in extract_stack(stack):
2022-05-30 15:00:27,007 1940 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating server reload
```

and i tried several solutions like increase

```
limit_request = 8192

limit_time_cpu = 600

limit_time_real = 1200

max_cron_threads = 1

limit_memory_hard = 536870637100

limit_memory_soft = 483183573400
```

but still facing same issue as error log, also i try to run the server after 30 mins as maximum i got same error again & again..

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Brother take a look at this link [Configuration suggestions for Odoo server](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/configuration-suggestions-for-odoo-server-with-1200-users-500-concurrent-87757)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VPS with 4 CPU cores and 16 GB of RAM, the number of workers should be 9 (CPU cores * 2 + 1), total limit-memory-soft value will be 640MB x 9 = 5760 MB , and total limit-memory-hard 768MB x 9 = 6912 MB,
so Odoo will use maximum 5.4 GB of RAM.

You server is 4vCPUs so try the below in your config file:

```
limit_memory_hard = 640MB * 9 * 1024 * 1024 = 7247757312
limit_memory_soft = 768MB * 9 * 1024 * 1024 = 6039797760
max_cron_threads = 1
workers = 8
```